# How to fix 'Android resource linking failed (failed processing manifest)' error in Flutter projects?

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-manifest

I ran into this issue recently while working on my project. Before this error, my flutter project was loading without a problem.

[image]

**this is my AndriodManifest.xml code**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.coffee_sellers_app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:label="coffee_sellers_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've tried running Flutter clean and even starting a new project, but the issue persists.

Comment: Are you posting the same question multiple times with different user id? Or is this just an unbelievable coincidence that someone has the same issue and also uses the same sentences... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344564/android-resource-linking-failed-failed-processing-manifest

Comment: Why multiple posts?

Comment: I apologize for creating a new account because I am unable to access my other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a xml file `network_security_config.xml` in `res/xml` folder.
The content of the XML file can be following

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```